# Flex Grids are not being responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a piano grid by simply using flex box. However, I am trying to make it responsive on all screen sizes. Basically, I place them on flex box container so that I can work on them individually.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
  <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>

</div>
```

Any idea what should I tweak to make it look good on smaller devices such as tablets and mobile phones?

Comment: The first step to responsiveness is NOT to use fixed pixel sizes.

Comment: try to use em instead

Comment: can you help with ems?

Comment: I can suggest an idea for mobile phones - rotate keys 90 degrees - `transform: rotate (90deg);`

Comment: why not you try bootstrap?

Comment: on mobile, all buttons would get very thin. Anyhow Rotation is needed.

Comment: Mind sharing the JSFIDDLE link of the updated answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: black;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            max-width: 80vw;
            background: black;
        }

        .key {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .white {
            width: 10vw;
            height: 35vh;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            border-left: 2px solid #333333;
        }

        .black {
            width: 7vw;
            height: 22vh;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            margin-left: -2vw;
            margin-right: -2vw;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .container {
                max-width: 90vw;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="C" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="D" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="E" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Eb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="G" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="A" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Bb" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="B" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key black"></div>
        <div data-keynote="Db" class="key white"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Steps I have taken to make improve your code are:

1. I replaced `#000` and `#000000` values with `black`, as it is much user friendly.
2. Instead of using values given in terms of percentage(%) of screen width/height, I used relative units of `vw` and `vh`, this makes your contents look similar across displays of various densities.
3. Furthermore, I changed z-index of 99 to 1, which doesn't create any difference but I like to follow the general conventions of increasing z-index progressively rather than putting arbitrary values.
4. Finally I enlarged width of container div for all small devices.

**NOTE:** I haven't done any alteration to the key class as it is never used in the code and I don't know what you wanted to do with it.